# Is it good to use same keyword for multiple pages in one domain?

Tags: seo, google-search

I want to know after Google recent updates, will it be good opt to use same keywords for multiple pages? Say- my keyword is "driver update" and I have a folder "HP" in website. Hp has lots of models like HP Elitebook, HP Envy, HP Mini, HP Pavilion and much more. HP Elitebook has many versions like HP Elitebook 2530p, HP Elitebook 2730p, HP Elitebook 8530w.

Now should I create pages like "Driver update in HP Elitebook 2530p" , "Driver update in HP Elitebook 2730p", "Driver update in P Elitebook 8530w" or a single page "Driver update in HP Elitebook"?

Which one will be the best option for better SE ranking- " single page or multiple pages using same keyword for different model versions" ?

Answer (score 1):

*Remember, search rank pages, not websites*

It's very okay to have the same keywords on ore then one page. It's very common and very natural.

In your example you want to create pages for each individual product as this gives you the opportunity to get the important keywords (model number, UPC number, etc) into the `<title>` and `<hx>` tags which is a good thing for SEO. Not only se-friendly, but better for your users as it helps them focus on the product they are looking for. (Usability is a big part of SEO).